# Rearranging java array elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What exactly am I doing wrong here and how do I fix it (please answer like I'm 5 as I am new to java and StackOverflow). The xyzToFront method is the one that should be responsible for the issue. I know there is a code that helps with rearranging/makes it simpler, but I am trying to work with/create my own algorithm according to what I learned.

Here is what I am getting:

> +[cat, dog, horse, zebra, zebra]
>
> - Expected: [cat, dog, horse, zebra, zebra]
>     +2
> - Expected: 2
>
> +3
>
> - Expected: 3
>
> -[xantus, xantus, yak, ape, dog, cat]
>
> - Expected: [xantus, zebra, yak, ape, dog, cat

Here is the code:

> // Complete the methods below. These methods manipulate Arrays of
>   Strings
>
> // Need help starting this question? In the lesson titled  //
>   "Starting points: Problem Set Questions", go to the // problem titled
>   "Problem Set 7 - Question 1" for some tips on  // how to begin.
>
> ```
>   import java.util.Arrays;
>
> public class ArrayMethods {
> String[] list; //instance variable
> /**
>  * Constructor for objects of class ArrayMethods
>  */
> public ArrayMethods(String[] list)
> {
>     // initialise instance variables
>     this.list = list;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Determines if the array is sorted (do not sort)
>  * When Strings are sorted, they are in alphabetical order
>  * Use the compareTo method to determine which string comes first
>  * You can look at the String compareTo method in the Java API
>  * @return true if the array  is sorted, else false.
>  */
> public boolean isSorted()
> {
>     boolean sorted = true;
>
>     // TODO: Write the code to loop through the array and determine that each
>     // successive element is larger than the one before it
>     for (int i = 1; i< list.length; i++){
>         if((list[i].compareTo(list[i-1]))>0){
>          sorted = false;   
>         }
>     }
>
>     return sorted;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Replaces all but the first and last with the larger of its to neighbors
>  * You can use the compareTo to determine which string is larger (later in alphabetical
>  * order).
>  */
> public void replaceWithLargerNeighbor()
> {
>     for(int i = 1; i<list.length-1; i++){
>         if ((list[i-1].compareTo(list[i+1]))> 0){
>          list[i] = list[i-1];   
>         }
>         else if(list[i-1].compareTo(list[i+1]) < 0){
>          list[i] = list[i+1];   
>         }
>     }
>
> }
>
> /**
>  * Gets the number of duplicates in the array.
>  * (Be careful to only count each duplicate once. Start at index 0. Does it match any of the other element?
>  * Get the next word. It is at index i. Does it match any of the words with index > i?)
>  * @return the number of duplicate words in the array.
>  */
> public int countDuplicates()
> {
>     int duplicates = 0;
>     for(int i = 0; i <list.length-1; i++){
>         for(int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
>             if(list[i].equals(list[j])){
>              duplicates++;   
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     return duplicates;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Moves any word that starts with x, y, or z to the front of the array, but
>  * otherwise preserves the order
>  */
> public void xyzToFront()
> {
>    String index = "";
>     int insertAt = 0;
>     for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
>     boolean startsWith = (list[i].startsWith("x") || list[i].startsWith("y") || list[i].startsWith("z"));
>
>         if(startsWith){  
>             index = list[i];
>             for(int j = i; j>0; j--){
>              list[j] = list[j-1];
>             }
>          list[insertAt] = index;
>             insertAt++;
>         }
>     }
>
> }
>
> /**
>  * gets the string representation of this array 
>  * @return a string representation of the array. (do this with Arrays.toString(list))
>  */
> public String toString()
> {
>     return Arrays.toString(list);
> } }
> ```

The following is the tester method that does not work with my answer for xyzToFront:

> String[] animals4 = {"ape", "dog", "xantus", "zebra", "cat", "yak"};
>   zoo = new ArrayMethods(animals4); zoo.xyzToFront();
>   System.out.println(zoo.toString()); System.out.println("Expected:
>   [xantus, zebra, yak, ape, dog, cat]");

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: No error, it just gets this -[xantus, xantus, yak, ape, dog, cat]

but this is expected: [xantus, zebra, yak, ape, dog, cat

Comment: I will update code to show tester method that isn't working with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was "insertAt" and not "0" as I put before. I guess somehow it was overwriting eachother.

> for(int j = i; j>insertAt; j--){